# Fim de entrada Scanner Java

Tags: java, c

Esse código em C faz a leitura de inteiros até ser digitado Control-Z (fim de entrada no windows).

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char line[100];
    int sum = 0;

    while(scanf("%s", line) == 1) {
        sum += atoi(line);
    }

    printf("%d\n", sum);
}
```

Como eu faço o mesmo utilizando o `Scanner` em Java ?

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português. Sua pergunta é sobre como simular o scanf em Java com a entrada até o CTRL+Z ou você quer apenas saber como fazer a entrada de dados em Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma possível solução seria assim:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        while (s.hasNextLine()) {
            String nextLine = s.nextLine();
            sum += Integer.parseInt(nextLine);
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pode usar a documentação da classe para entender os métodos que ela possui: [**`Scanner`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

Segue um exemplo simples (não testado):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SimpleScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int sum = 0;
        while (s.hasNextInt()) {
            sum += s.nextInt();
        }

        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

O loop seria equivalente ao seguinte em C++:

```cpp
int i;
while (cin >> i) {
    sum += i;
}
```